# Help with SAML error: "Keyset does not exist"

Tags: c#, saml

We have two environments that should be identical but one of them raises an error when we try to generate a SAML message signature. I haven't looked at SAML before and I am not exactly sure what it tries to do

Part of the code:

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = (X509Certificate2)Application[ASP.global_asax.IdPX509Certificate];

        try
        {
            SAMLMessageSignature.Generate(samlResponse, x509Certificate.PrivateKey, x509Certificate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            app = File.AppendText(@"C:\SAML.txt");
            app.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            app.Flush();
            app.Close();
        }
```

The exception message is

> Keyset does not exist

Does anyone have any idea of what I should be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that is loading the X509Certificate2 into the HttpApplicationState object?

Answer (score 4):

Hi please check the following on your setup.

- Set the correct access control entries, ACLs, to the certificate you installed.
- Add Modify access role for NETWORK SERVICE to the certificate.
- If you are using Windows 2008 and Windows 7, you can access the private key from the certificate 
  snap-in in the MMC.

  [image: Manage Private Keys]
- If it still did not work, add Modify access role also for IIS_IUSRS.
  [image: IIS_IUSRS]

Hope it will help you.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the certificate stored in the HttpApplicationState object's key `ASP.global_asax.IdPX509Certificate` was loaded successfully.  If the certificate is being loaded from a PFX file, ensure that it is present on the disk and accessible by the account your web app is running under. If the certificate is being loaded from a certificate store, ensure that it is installed in the correct store and that the account your web app is running under can access the certificate.

You can use **winhttpcertcfg.exe** to install certificates into system keystores and manage certificate ACLs. The KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901183 contains some additional info.